# How to update a value at a position inside a comma separated string mysql

Tags: mysql, database, csv, insert-update

I have a column with the following data 8,12,17,18.

I want to update a value at a particular position

For eg .I want to change 17 which comes at position 3 to 25.
I want to change the values depending on its position inside the 
comma separated string.

Comment: you want to change CSV data using ... MySQL?

Comment: I have a column named products in MySQL table so I have to update the value at a particular position of that column value

Comment: maybe a redesign of your schema is in order ? either create a new table or maybe "SET" can help you -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Comment: Sounds Interesting,but redesigning won't Help as I have loads of data in my table.And also set datatype takes a maximum of 64 elements.But in my case I have more than 100 elements in a set.

Comment: Then I recommend to use another table. I know at this point it might be painful, but on the long run, it will be better

Comment: But what about having more than 64 elements in a set

Comment: you can't, it's a limitation of MySQL